# Get user field category

Tags: plugin-development, categories, field

I have a matrix that contains a block with a category field. I want to loop over the matrix models, ***in PHP***, to get data. Here's what I have so far:

```
foreach ($user->networksMatrix as $key => $networkLink)
{
    $netArr[$networkLink->id]["fields"]["networktype"] = $networkLink->networktype;
    $netArr[$networkLink->id]["fields"]["networkUrl"] = $networkLink->networkUrl;
}
```

**networktype** is a category field. How do I get the get the ID of the category a user selected?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the following works:

```
foreach ($user->networksMatrix as $key => $networkLink)
{
    $netArr[$networkLink->id]["fields"]["networktype"] = $networkLink->networktype->ids()[0];
    $netArr[$networkLink->id]["fields"]["networkUrl"] = $networkLink->networkUrl;
}
```

Since **networktype** is a categories field and that field is limited to 1 category I'll only ever get a single result from the method:

```
ids();
```

So... I just do this and I'm good:

```
$networkLink->networktype->ids()[0];
```

Comment: That's great, Matt! Would you mind adding that as an official answer rather than an update to the original question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: The part where you updated your question with a solution.  Can you add that under the "Your Answer" portion on the bottom of the page?  That adds it as an official answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, the question was resolved by the asker and I will quote his answer here, so this fine question is recognized by Stack Exchange as answered!

Matt V says:

> I discovered that the following works:
>
> ```
> foreach ($user->networksMatrix as $key => $networkLink)
> {
>     $netArr[$networkLink->id]["fields"]["networktype"] = $networkLink->networktype->ids()[0];
>     $netArr[$networkLink->id]["fields"]["networkUrl"] = $networkLink->networkUrl;
> }
> ```
>
> Since networktype is a categories field and that field is limited to 1
>   category I'll only ever get a single result from the method:
>
> ```
> ids();
> ```
>
> So... I just do this and I'm good:
>
> ```
> $networkLink->networktype->ids()[0];
> ```